# Can you list iptables as a non-root user? and why?

Tags: iptables, root, firewall, capabilities

Is it at all possible to execute the `iptables --list …`  command
without being root?

Running it as non-root prints this:

```
$ iptables --list
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

If you must be root to list iptables,
what is the reasoning behind that? 
Is there a security concern with viewing the rules? 
Is there a resource or service used by `iptables --list`
that requires root access?

Obviously, modifying iptables firewall rules requires privileges. 
I am asking about viewing them.

---

Instead of being root,
is there a capability that could permit listing the rules? 
Does iptables use netlink to interface with the kernel? 
Because [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) mentions that

> Only processes with an effective UID of 0 or the **`CAP_NET_ADMIN`**
> capability may send or listen to a netlink multicast group.

Maybe that does not apply to iptables.

I am not sure whether this is the right way of doing it,
but adding a capability to `iptables`
does not let me list the rules, either:

```
bash-4.1$ echo $UID
2000
bash-4.1$ getcap /sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7
/sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7 = cap_net_admin+ep
bash-4.1$ /sbin/iptables-multi-1.4.7 main --list
FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/3.10.0-514.21.1.el7.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory
iptables v1.4.7: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

---

Here are some relevant questions:

- [iptables – add rules not as root](https://superuser.com/questions/564117/iptables-add-rules-not-as-root)    (Super User)
- [Using iptables without root privileges](https://serverfault.com/questions/636442/using-iptables-without-root-privileges) (Server Fault)

Both provide workarounds, in my opinion,
and do not discuss the fundamental reason behind the restriction.

Comment: Do those linked questions really include a workaround though?  I see suggestions to just use root and/or to use sudo, but both of those would allow the users to also modify rules no?

Comment: As a workaround they suggest to wrap `sudo iptables` in a script or call iptables in a cron job by root. I thought of these as workarounds to fall back to the privileged user in a different way.

Comment: Yea, but your question has me thinking there is a good use case for more granular `iptables` permissions.   The first thing I thought when I read this was low tier support personnel could need the ability to view firewall rules as part of initial troubleshooting on an incident but have no access to modify them.  If you gave them sudo permissions you would be giving them way more than just view iptables.  Even as one person suggested giving them permission to sudo a script could be problematic but that sounds like the closest thing so far.

Answer (score 14):

It appears `iptables` needs both CAP_NET_RAW and CAP_NET_ADMIN to be able to read the tables. I tried

```
$ cp /usr/sbin/iptables ~/iptables  # note, it may be a symbolic link
$ sudo setcap CAP_NET_RAW,CAP_NET_ADMIN+ep  ~/iptables
$ ~/iptables  -nvL
```

and it was ok.

Comment: The true answer, for a huge class of problems

Comment: As of Linux 5.15 (and Ubuntu 22.04) I can run `iptables -nvL` with only the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, `iptables` uses the netlink interface to communicate with the kernel. It opens a netlink socket to `xtables`, then issues commands via this socket. Access control is performed when the socket is opened, not for individual commands, so the same permissions are required for listing and modifying rules. The only way to allow a user to list rules but not modify them is to give them a carefully-written setuid (or setcap) executable.

It would be nice if there was an interface to netfilter in `/proc`, but as far as I know the task of implementing it has never been completed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
$ cat iptables-list.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    if (setuid(0) != 0)
    {
        perror("setuid");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    execl("/sbin/iptables", "iptables", "-L", "-n", NULL);
    perror("execl");
}
$ gcc -Wall -Werror -o iptables-list -s iptables-list.c
$ sudo mv iptables-list /sbin/iptables-list
$ sudo chown 0.0 /sbin/iptables-list
$ sudo chmod 4755 /sbin/iptables-list
$ ls -l /sbin/iptables-list
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 5552 Feb 23 08:14 /sbin/iptables-list
$ iptables-list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
...
```

Comment: Please note that the original question is for situations without root access: `sudo` **is** root access, and __setuid__ bit requires root access too.

Comment: @Samveen Indeed, but making a root-owned compiled program that holds the setuid bit and runs just one fixed command is (somewhat) more secure than using an administrator-prepared script with `sudo`, as it eliminates both the `sudo` and the shell from the chain, resulting in much less privileged code to run and so reduced potential of weaknesses. This is **exactly** the original recommended practice for granting a regular user limited access to some administrative function from back when `sudo` did not exist and/or administrators didn't just assume that shells are bullet-proof.

Comment: on google colab, '!iptables-list' gives:
'execl: Operation not permitted'

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS Focal,
I had to set `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH`, `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capabilities.

If you set only `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN`,
you will see such error:

```
Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied
```

Let’s see how it works:

```
$ sudo cp /usr/sbin/ip6tables ~/ip6tables

$ sudo setcap cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep ./ip6tables # not enough caps
$ ./ip6tables -nvL
Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied

# CAP_NET_RAW + CAP_NET_ADMIN + CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH capabilities
$ sudo setcap cap_dac_read_search,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ep ./ip6tables 
$ ./ip6tables -nvL # works fine
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1813K packets, 4509M bytes)
=== /// ===
```

Also, please note if you are trying to run a program and executing ip6tables as a child process,
then you have to pass required capabilities to such child process.

For Golang, please see [this pr](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/19713) and [this code](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/43512/13/src/syscall/exec_linux_test.go#538)